# how to merge based on boolean condition in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames, e.g.

```
>>>df1
datetime                 id
2018-01-01 1:00:11       abc
2018-01-01 12:00:00     flllds

>>>df2
datetime2                id
2018-01-01 1:30:11      abc
2018-01-01 1:30:32      abc
2018-01-01 2:30:32      abc
2018-01-01 12:00:00     flllds
```

I have to join the data frames based on the `id` and select rows where `datetime - datetime2` < 1 hour

My issue is that my data frames are huge, so I get a `MemoryError` when I 
first merge and then filter based on condition.

Is there a way I can limit the size of the data frame during the merge?

> df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['id'])

Comment: How do you join the dataframes and perform your selection? Please edit your question and add the relevant code. And which one do you use - Python 3 or Python 2? Please remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: I use python 3 .df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['id'])

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to limit the size of a merge. I would just do this in chunks, get a list of unique keys, do x number of keys at time, save that dataframe to disk and do the next. Then you can combine the files at the end. This also looks like a good use case for Python Dask https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-overview.html